# SFML C++ collision detection after transformation

Tags: c++, collision, transformation, sfml

In my work to create an excavator, I have got the body, upper arm, lower arm and claws attached using transformation.

I have to use collision detection for my claws in the image below. I have to use transformation for the body at position 200,200, upper arm at position 0,0, lower arm at position 0,0 and then the claws at position 0,0 to attach them together.

For example bodyAtpart2 * grabber, note: bodyAtPart2 is the body * upper arm * lower arm, grabber is the claw.

My task is to do a collision between the claws and the circles I have created.

Every time I try to use `grabber.getGlobalBounds().intersects(intersectionCirc.getGlobalBounds()` but
it does not work because the translation of the grabber is at 0,0 even after transformation it did not get the coordinates of the body. Therefore my code could not compare with the circle's position.

If I position my claws it would ruined the position, for example, if I have position the body at 200,200 then the claws at 300,200, so the claws would be 500,400 out of the window or disjointed from the lower arm and certainly would not collide with the circles.

[image: Assignment]

Comment: Could you give some code as to the structure of your classes, in particular that of the `grabber`? Which of the entities are `Drawable`/`Transformable`, and do you have a scene graph or how exactly are the parts of the excavator linked? Might the `Shape` you draw actually not in itself have the transformation info, but rather you pass it to draw with the state of the encompassing entity?

Comment: I got this working when I used transformation points. When I draw it, must draw obj, transform then they were linked. Thanks for your reply.